# Bootstrap template not working correctly with custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mcustomscrollbar

I have downloaded a simple bootstrap template with a fixed sidebar (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/) and tried to integrate custom scroll bar in it (http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) but once the plugin runs

```
 $("#sidebar-wrapper").mCustomScrollbar()
```

or

```
 $("#sidebar-wrapper").mCustomScrollbar({theme: "minimal-dark"})
```

the menu becomes a black screen. I created this fiddle to show this behaviour https://jsfiddle.net/9qawf6r3/. Here is another example working: http://jsfiddle.net/wuj2v604/

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `background-color` property in `.mCustomScrollBox` class .

Its coming from jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css .

```
.mCustomScrollBox {
    direction: ltr;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    outline: 0 none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Add `background-color:#FFF !important;` or wtever color you want.

EDIT : add this css too

```
#mCSB_1_container{
  height:100%;
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv2p4bhw/)

Comment: Did it but, no change. Menu content is still missing and the scroll bar too.

Comment: Thanks @p2 now I can see the menu, though I do not understand what is happening with the scrollbar.

Comment: @Leo : if ur issue is resolved , cn u upvote and accept the ans

Comment: No, sorry but it is not yet fixed. I want the scroll working but it's not. I am only seeing the menu now but not the scrollbar.